# Low disk space on Manjaro / , how to resize /dev/mapper/ partitions?

Tags: partition

I have Manjaro Linux installed on my laptop. When I log in I get a message

```
Only 0.22GB or 28.71 GB left on /
```

Previous suggestions were to run Pacman -Scc to clear the pacman cache, and that worked for a while, but now its still warning me after I do that.

I opened up GParted to look at the partitions, and I basically have one large Partition for the system.

Running df -h shows the following (which doesn't match what I see in GParted):

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                                1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
run                                1.9G  1.1M  1.9G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroRoot   29G   28G  226M 100% /  
tmpfs                              1.9G  104K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              1.9G   56K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3                          248M   97M  139M  42% /boot
/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroHome  426G  122G  283G  31% /home
/dev/sda2                           99M  356K   99M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              385M   20K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
```

This /dev/mapper/ partitions are new to me. Can someone explain how they work, and how I can resize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are logical volumes, so you can resize them using `lvresize`.

However, that is just the resizing of the underlying block device, you still have to resize the filesystem on top of it, and the way to do this will depend on the filesystem type and its initial configuration.

Most commonly used Linux filesystems support online resizing, ext2-based use `resize2fs` and xfs uses `xfs_growfs`.

Comment: I realise that mysql binay logs were taking up a ton of space there. Probably better I put them somewhere else